# Sorting not seeming to work

Tags: shell-script

I am currently writing a webcrawl bot. It generates a list of URLs, and I need it to remove duplicates, and sort the lines alphabetically. My code looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
URL="google.com"
while [ 1 ]; do
  wget --output-document=dl.html $URL
  links=($(grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' dl.html))
  printf "%s\n" ${links[@]} >> results.db

  sort results.db | uniq -u

  URL=$(shuf -n 1 results.db)
  echo $URL
done
```

Spefifcially the line:

```
sort results.db | uniq -u
```

Comment: post a snapshot of contents of `results.db`.

Comment: Just `sort -u results.db` is simpler.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Are you getting the urls to your screen instead of back into a file?

Comment: Prepare to be blocked by Google if you're actually running automated queries against google.com.  Check their terms of service.

Comment: here's a better way to extract links from a html file or URL: `lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "$URL" >> results.db`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) says of `uniq -u`:

> Suppress the writing of lines that are repeated in the input.

which means that any line which is repeated (even the original line) will be filtered out.  What you meant was probably (done with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) also):

```
sort -u results.db
```

For `sort -u`, POSIX says

> Unique: suppress all but **one** in each set of lines having equal keys. If used with the -c option, check that there are no lines with duplicate keys, in addition to checking that the input file is sorted.

In either case, the following line

```
URL=$(shuf -n 1 results.db)
```

probably assumes that the purpose of sort/uniq is to *update* `results.db` (it won't).  You would have to modify the script a little more for that:

```
sort -u results.db >results.db2 && mv results.db2 results.db
```

or (as suggested by @drewbenn), combine it with the previous line.  However, since that *appends* to the file (combining the commands as shown in his answer won't eliminate the duplicates between the latest printf and the file's contents), a separate command sort/mv looks closer to the original script.

If you want to ensure that `$URL` is not empty, that's (actually another question), and done by the `[` test, e.g.,

```
  [ -n "$URL" ] && wget --output-document=dl.html $URL
```

though simply exiting from the loop would be simpler:

```
[ -z "$URL" ] && break
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an improved version of your script.

It's still pretty crappy because (apart from a bare minimum effort with the initial google search), it makes no attempt to deal with any of the truly awful things that an unfortunately large percentage of web sites do to `A HREF` URLs - either because they're incompetent or because they're trying to track you or both.

```
#! /bin/sh

# exit on any error
set -e    

dbfile="results.db"

# if "$dbfile" doesn't exist (or is empty), or if a URL has been
# provided as a command-line argument, fetch the initial URLs
# from "$1" (or a google search), and strip off the google-junk:

if [ ! -s "$dbfile" ] || [ -n "$1" ] ; then 
    URL="{$1:-https://www.google.com/search?q=interesting+stuff}"

    lynx -accept_all_cookies -dump -listonly -nonumbers "$URL" | 
        sed -e '/^http.*url?/!d; s/^.*\/url?q=//; s/\&.*//' > "$dbfile"

fi

URL=$(shuf -n 1 "$dbfile")

while [ 1 ]; do
  lynx -accept_all_cookies -dump -listonly -nonumbers "$URL" | 
      grep http >> "$dbfile"

  tmpfile=$(mktemp) && 
    sort -u "$dbfile" > "$tmpfile" &&
    mv -f "$tmpfile" "$dbfile" &&
    rm -f "$tmpfile"

  URL=$(shuf -n 1 "$dbfile")
  echo "$URL"
done
```

Web scraping is difficult, mostly because HTML is an extremely lax standard, but also because web designers are often either incompetent retards or attempting to deliberately obfuscate their pages, or both.  It needs a more capable language than `bash`.

Personally, I write web robots in `perl`, with `libwww-perl` aka `LWP`.   I particularly like the `HTML::TokeParser` perl module as a reasonably simple HTML parser in combination with `LWP`.